# PHP Cron Job from cPanel not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am using Codeigniter 3 and using the cPanel to run a Cron Job.

I have entered the command like this:
`php /home/name/public_html/ convert`

When loading the page for my controllers I do not need to include `index.php` so I did not include it in my path above. `convert` is the name of my controller.

I receive a `404 Not Found` when using the above command. If I change it to:

`php /home/name/public_html/index.php convert`

I recieve this error:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: REQUEST_METHOD</p>
<p>Filename: core/Security.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 208</p>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Does anyone see anything wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: by the looks of it the script wants server variables - which it wont get when run from the command line. options are preferable- rewrite  script or use the option below

Comment: I've had to resort to just running `curl http://example.com/controller/function`

Comment: @JeremyJackson Can that be done from the cPanel Cron jobs command?

Comment: @JeremyJackson usig `curl` worked for me. I am not sure If I should answer my own question or if you want to write that as the answer.

Comment: Answered :) And can it be done that way?

Comment: yes, I was able to add the curl to the cron job command and it worked for me. now i just need to figure out how to check if it was completed so I can start another php function :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to resort to just running

```
curl http://example.com/controller/function
```